# Intercepting and Processing Messages Before Broadcasting with Socket.io Redis Adapter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, redis, socket.io, scaling

I'm working on a real-time chat application using Socket.io and its Redis adapter for scalability across multiple instances. One of the features I want to implement is automatic message translation based on each user's preferred language.

The flow I envision is as follows:

1. A user submits a message. The server captures it and broadcasts it to a room using the redis-adapter.
2. Upon detecting a new message on Redis, an instance retrieves the message, identifies the members in the room, and translates the message according to each recipient's language setting.
3. Every client in the room then receives the message in their chosen language.

**Question:** Is there a way to intercept and process messages before broadcasting them to clients in a room using the Socket.io Redis adapter? Ideally, I'd like to handle the translation server-side before the message reaches the clients, eliminating the need for additional client-server requests.

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Currently, the only solution I've come up with is to send the original message to all clients in the room with `io.in(room).emit('message', msg);`, and then each client makes an additional "processMessage" request to the server with their language preference. The server then translates the message and sends it back. However, this approach seems inefficient as it involves a lot of back-and-forth between the client and the server.

I attempted to check if the `io.on('message', msg)` event triggers on the server side. However, it appears that only the clients are receiving the message.

Actually, when examining the diagram from the documentation of the redis-adapter, it doesn't appear to be feasible. However, it might be possible with the mongodb-adapter.

Redis adapter :

[Redis adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4nSO.png)

MongoDB adapter :

[MongoDB adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BJPO.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.